# How can I make my bot play audio faster? (discord.py rewrite)

Tags: python, discord.py

My music takes about 30 seconds or more to start playing audio, and I want to know if there's any way I can make it play audio faster like Groovy and many other bots can. All help with this is appreciated. I know streaming it directly from yt is a thing, and my bot currently downloads and extracts the file, then plays it. Here is my code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['p', 'pla'])
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    global voice
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()

    await voice.disconnect()

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
        print(f"The bot has connected to {channel}\n")

    def check_queue():
        Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
        if Queue_infile is True:
            DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue"))
            length = len(os.listdir(DIR))
            still_q = length - 1
            try:
                first_file = os.listdir(DIR)[0]
            except:
                print("No more queued song(s)\n")
                queues.clear()
                return
            main_location = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
            song_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue") + "\\" + first_file)
            if length != 0:
                print("Song done, playing next queued\n")
                print(f"Songs still in queue: {still_q}")
                song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
                if song_there:
                    os.remove("song.mp3")
                shutil.move(song_path, main_location)
                for file in os.listdir("./"):
                    if file.endswith(".mp3"):
                        os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')

                voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: check_queue())
                voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
                voice.source.volume = 0.07

            else:
                queues.clear()
                return

        else:
            queues.clear()
            print("No songs were queued before the ending of the last song\n")
```

Comment: Maybe [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for that.

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what causes it to be slow but think that probably it's related to the internet connection your pc/host service has, I think you should try streaming directly from youtube to make it faster

```py
queue = []

YDL_OPTIONS = = {
            "format" : "bestaudio",
            "postprocessors" : [{
                "key" : "FFmpegExtractAudio",
                "preferredcodec" : "mp3",
                "preferredquality" : "192",
            }], "noplaylist" : "True"
        }

FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

def play_next():
    queue.pop(0)
    if len(queue) >= 1:
        source = queue[0]['source']
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(queue[0]['source'], FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: play_next())
        voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
        voice.source.volume = 0.07

def lstr(list : Iterable):
        string = f"{list[0]}"
        for i in range(1, len(list)):
            string += f" {list[i]}"
        return string

def search_yt(item):
        with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            try: 
                info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % item, download=False)['entries'][0]
            except Exception: 
                return False

        return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}

@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['p', 'pla'])
async def play(ctx, *query):
    query = lstr(query)
    song = search_yt(query)
    queue.append[song]
    global voice
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()

    await voice.disconnect()

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
        print(f"The bot has connected to {channel}\n")

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(queue[0]['source'], FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: play_next())
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.07
```

Or you can get a host and that will make it a little bit faster ;)

Comment: This streaming code didn't work, it says `Iterable is not defined`

Comment: try to import Iterable